# Pickle not creating and writing to a file?

Tags: python, passwords, pickle

I am trying to create a program that writes user input to a text document, but it is not working.

It just loops this one section over and over again. Here is my current code:

```
else:
    #Creates a new file and writes the pasword to it 
    print("Strong Password")
    password1 += password1
    newName = input("What do you want to save this password as? ")
    print(newName)
    file = open("passwordstorer", "w")
    file.write(newName)
    file.write(password1)
    file.close()

    break
```

Comment: Can we see more of your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `with open` instead of manually closing everytime. I doubt that it is the source for your error, but you never know. Like this:

`else:`

```
print("Strong Password")
password1 += password1
newName = input("What do you want to save this password as? ")
print(newName)
with open("passwordstorer.txt, "w") as file:
    file.write(newName)
    file.write(password1)

 file.close()
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the v0rtex use with, it's cleaner.

But your problem i believe is that you are using **input**(which is for ints)
vs **raw_input** (for raw string input)

This depends on what version of python you are using. raw_input doesn't exist in python3 and input is used for both in python3.
So if you could verify your python version.

Also saving raw text passwords in a file might be kind of dangerous, maybe you should look in to salt/hashing it.

Comment: Yes, exactly NameError is possible if it's python2. There could be a *try* silently catching the error. Which is why i'm asking for the version, and not jumping to conclusions.